# values ​different from the sum of what was to be c language

Tags: c, input, sum, output

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int A, B;
    int SOMA = A+B;
    scanf("%d%d", &A, &B);
    printf("SOMA = %d\n", SOMA);

    return 0;
}

/*
INPUT --> OUTPUT
30 10 --> SOMA = 16
1  3  --> SOMA = 16
300 1000 --> SOMA = 16
*/
```

why am i getting these results instead of the sum?
I wanted the message "SOMA = sumValue" with the end of the line.

Comment: This is C, not C++. Please don't use random language tags!

Comment: Please don't tag C++ in C questions

Comment: `int SOMA = A+B;` needs to be *after* you read the values for `A` and `B`.

Comment: You can't calculate `SOMA` before you read `A` and `B`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int SOMA = A+B;
scanf("%d%d", &A, &B);
```

You are adding `A` and `B` before the user has input any values. Reverse those two.

Comment: thanks for the patience to explain. I started studying C not long ago and I still make pretty silly mistakes

Answer (score 1):

C is not Excel.  This:

```
int SOMA = A+B;
```

Does not tie the value of `SOMA` to the value of `A+B`.  This sets `SOMA` to the *current* value of `A+B`, neither of which has been initialized.

You need to read the values of `A` and `B` first, *then* set the value of `SOMA` based on that.

```
scanf("%d%d", &A, &B);
int SOMA = A+B;
```

Answer (score 0):

C is an imperative language. `SOMA = A+B` is executed where you wrote it, i.e. before you even saved the values the user entered in `A` and `B`.

(This is *really* basic. Maybe find a better introduction to C!)